# Accesing a RESTORED db from Data Studio

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have restored a db from db2 express-c 11.1 version to a db2 developer version. I can access the tables and data from db2 cmd but when I'm getting the following error message when trying to access tables/view/... in IBM DATA Studio.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20249, SQLSTATE=     , SQLERRMC=NULLID.SYSSH200, DRIVER=3.69.56
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.c(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.p(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.h(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.i(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.ib(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.yo.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.internal.core.connection.StatementAdapter.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.prs.PRSDatabaseLoader.processQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.prs.PRSDatabaseLoader.initiateQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.prs.PRSQueryInfo.getSlice(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentQueryCache.getSlice(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSet.createSlice(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSet.isClosed(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSet.checkNotClosed(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSet.absolute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSet.relative(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.internal.core.util.PersistentResultSetAdapter.next(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.core.db2.luw.load.catalog.LUWCatalogDatabase.loadSchemas(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.core.db2.luw.load.catalog.LUWCatalogDatabase.getSchemas(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.LoadUtility$9.basicLoad(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.ChildrenLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.LoadManager$LevelLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.LoadManager$LevelLoader.doWork(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.LoadManager$LevelLoader.access$0(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.datatools.uom.internal.content.loadmgr.LoadManager$LevelLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you successfully restore a Db2-LUW database to a new Db2-instance it is wise to ensure that you rebind all of the IBM supplied bindfiles to the database.

The CLI bindfiles are part of your Db2-client, and it's wise to ensure that your Db2-client version/fixpack matches that of the Db2-server.

Rebinding CLI utilities is essential if the Db2-version or Db2-fixpack of the restore-database differs from the original database.

To rebind CLI utilities, follow IBM's instructions for rebinding the CLI packages [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0007866.html).

Another useful activity is to revalidate database objects if the Db2 version or fixpack has changed. There's a stored procedure for that, see details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html).

**Note**: if your database contains SQL PL stored procedures or static-SQL packages then you may also need to rebind those packages to take advantage of any Db2 version differences. There are different ways to do this, but one way is to use [db2rbind](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001995.html) , and this should only be done on development/testing environments where you can validate the results.

Comment: I executed this command

db2 bind "%DB2PATH%\bnd\@db2cli.lst" blocking all grant public

and it outputs the following result

LINE    MESSAGES FOR db2cli.lst
------  --------------------------------------------------------------------
        SQL0061W  The binder is in progress.
        SQL0091N  Binding was ended with "0" errors and "0" warnings.
db2 => bind db2schema.bnd blocking all grant public

but I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: You must also rebind the *other* supplied files, e.g. db2clipk.bnd as mentioned on the referenced documentation page.

Comment: There's also db2ubind.lst to be bound, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/t0004951.html

Answer (score 3):

I followed the answer written by [mao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8290634/mao) here but it didn't help.
What helped is rebinding all packages and then re-validating them.

One can use below commands to rebind all packages:

```
db2 connect to SAMPLE

db2 -x "select 'REBIND PACKAGE ' || rtrim(pkgschema) || '.' || rtrim(pkgname) || ';' as command from syscat.packages" > rebind.sql

db2 -tvf rebind.sql
```

Post rebinding, re-validate all objects using below system store procedure:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS()
```

Comment: This helped me! But I had to rebind a specific package myself, because this command would give me the error "SQL20249N  The statement was not processed because the package named "NULLID.SQLC2P31" needs to be explicitly rebound." So I executed "db2 rebind package NULLID.SQLC2P31" and things started working.